# Doubt about Totally Bounded and Complete Subset $\implies$ Compact Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the following statement. I can understand all the nuances of the notes I'm using but the highlighted part below.

It's clear for me that if $A$ is sequentially compact, then it's totally bounded and I can always cover it with a finite number of closed balls of arbitrarily small radius.

Here comes the confusion: the balls are *closed in $X$*, not in $A$, I think. Hence, my doubts are on these two points:

1) Why will the intersections of the closed balls with $A$ be also closed sets?

2) Moreover, are they *closed in $X$* or *closed in $A$*? This is the most confusing part.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a set is sequentially compact, it is sequentially closed, and so it is closed. Thus, $A_1$ is closed in $X$ since intersection of two closed sets of $X$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what a sequentially closed set is and how sequentially compact implies sequentially closed.

Comment: it means that if a sequence of elements of $A$ converges to some element $x\in X$, then $x$ must belong to $A$. So if $A$ is sequentially compact and a sequence of elements of $A$ converges to some element $x\in X$, then by sequential compactness, a subsequence converges to an element of $A$, which implies that $x$ must be in $A$. So $A$ is sequentially closed.